# DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY while using scroll view

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.`

I need to ask why i need to give a specific width and height while using scroll view?
 This is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/lin_1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/iv_professonal_detail_info"
                                    android:tag="image_tag"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_weight="2"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/tv_name_detail_info"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/tv_designation_detail_info"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/tv_experience_detail_info"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:text="Specialization: "
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/list_specialization"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:text="Education:"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/list_education"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:text="Experiences:"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/list_experience"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                                />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_link"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="View User Feedback"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:clickable="true"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <!-- The navigation drawer -->
            <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#e5e5e5"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I actually need a scroll view. Its working if i give a specific width and height but i donot want to use that because it may varies with phone dimensions. Please help

Comment: "I need to ask why i need to give a specific width and height while using scroll view?" - That's just how `DrawerLayout` works. It's most likely because it would take an intensive amount of calculation to layout its child `View`s with an inexact measure, especially when opening/closing the drawer. Are you sure you don't want just the main content to scroll?

Comment: I want the main content to scroll. But if I give specific measurement to drawer layout than all the alignment done also gets affected.

Comment: I mean putting the `ScrollView` inside the `DrawerLayout`, as the main content, the first `ViewGroup`. The way you have it now, the whole `DrawerLayout`, including the drawer, would scroll as one. Usually, the main content would scroll independently of the drawer.

Comment: Please suggest me the best way

Comment: I tried putting the scrollview inside drawer. I mean in the frame layout also. But then the last textview didn't gets scrolled. I mean i can't have an access of it

Comment: The simplest way would be to just replace the `FrameLayout` tags with `ScrollView` tags, and remove the outer `ScrollView`. Then change the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: That's probably because you have `match_parent` for the `LinearLayout`'s `layout_height`.

Comment: Still gets the same exception     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Comment: Change the `DrawerLayout`'s `layout_width` to `match_parent`.

Comment: Changed. But now didnt get any exception but there is no scrolling and also last textview is not displayed in the screen

Comment: You have a redundant `LinearLayout`. That is, you don't need one of the outermost `LinearLayout`s. Get rid of one, and make sure that the `layout_height` on the remaining one is `wrap_content`.

Comment: Yes, I also found this error , but my text view gets cut, and no proper scrolling

Comment: Oh, you have a `ListView` and a `RecyclerView` nested inside a `ScrollView`. That's going to cause problems. You can try using a `NestedScrollView` instead, or you can take those out of the `ScrollView`, and put them all inside another `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110604/discussion-between-priyanka-minhas-and-mike-m).